# Get last 4 digits of card from PaymentIntent object in Stripe PHP

Tags: php, stripe-payments

Is it possible to get the last 4 digits of a card from the PaymentIntent object (not same as Charges API) using Stripe PHP SDK?

Answer (score 8):

You can get from `Charge` object included in `PaymentIntent`.

```
PaymentIntent->charges->data
```

https://stripe.com/docs/api/charges/object

Comment: The code would be `$payment_intent->charges->data[0]->payment_method_details->card->last4;`

Comment: @koopajah I'm currently working with this, however with the test_key I do not receive a charges object on my confirm API response. The test payment is successful. Stripe doesn't return some data while test_keys are in use. Would you possibly know if this is one of those cases? Thanks for your time!

Comment: I'd recommend talking to Stripe's support team. The charge would definitely be here if the call succeeded and they can help you debug this

Comment: Are you generating a test event from the dashboard or CLI? In this case it often leaves a lot of the data blank. I have found that the data is more complete if you enter a full payment using the forms in test mode, using one of the test cards. I was able to get complete data in the objects only when using the forms in test mode and entering the data manually. IMHO the CLI and dashboard test objects are inadequate for thorough testing and it's best ot just skip them because they omit so much data that would never be allowed to be omitted in a live integration.